# Why is VisualVM running 50 threads for VisualVM itself?

Tags: java, multithreading, visualvm

## Update

A different way to ask this question is "Is there ever a point to having more threads available to the application than there are cores?".

## Original Question

I have a total of 8 cores on my laptop.  I just downloaded the latest version of VisualVM and clicked on the `VisualVM` tab to see how it is performing.  One of the things I noticed is that it's using 32 live threads and 22 daemon threads.  Why is it using so many?  IIUC using more than 8 is less efficient, and IIUC the JVM knows how many cores I have so it could just limit the total number of threads to 8.

Someone marked this as a duplicate, so I'll try to explain what I'm asking a little differently.  I'm not asking how to use a particular feature of VisualVM.  I'm asking why it is running more than 8 threads, since IIUC more than 8 would be less than optimal and VisualVM comes from Oracle so I figured they would design it to function optimally, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something, or is Oracle just allowing it to run with more threads than it should be running with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting Profiling in Visual VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770851/limiting-profiling-in-visual-vm)

Comment: "Profiled threads limit.. always 32" https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/profiling-with-visualvm,-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have 50 threads of VisualVM running, it doesn't necessarily mean that all of those threads are supposed to be working actively at the same time. If you sort on the "Running" column, you will see that only the first 7 or 8 threads are actively running. The rests of the threads are sleeping or waiting for I/O.

Comment: An answer that says *what* the extra threads are doing would be more helpful: the "waiting for I/O" is in the right direction but still vague.

Comment: Your answer makes sense - But it still looks like a design flaw to me based on my current understanding of how concurrent java solutions should be designed.  Since Oracle made this, I'm wondering if they know something I don't.  In particular I'm wondering why they did not just use a shared executor pool with a max of 8 threads in this case for the entire app - is there some benefit to doing what they are doing?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in having more number of threads than the number of cores. in fact it is a standard practice, not just with Oracle. The advantage is, like I said, when one CPU core is free because that thread is currently waiting for I/O or something, it can still handle the other thread rather than sitting idle.

Comment: That logic makes sense.  For example if we are making one hundred asynchronous rest requests and awaiting slow responses then we might as well dedicate an asynchronous thread to each request and handle all of them in parallel.

Comment: Looking at it slightly differently suppose I have 2 cores and 2 threads.  One of the threads is busy computing fibonacci numbers while the other is waiting for a database operation that is also performed on the same machine.  In this case the database is then probably using the other core, so having for example 4 threads in this scenario might lead to excessive context switching, so in the end it seems this is something that would have to be tuned ...?